# Mostrar campos de modelos relacionados en el template de django

Tags: python, django

Tengo estos dos modelos, `Invoice` que representa una factura e `Item` que representa los articulos en la factura.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Invoice(models.Model):
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=200)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Invoice number: {}".format(self.number)

class Item(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    notes = models.TextField()
    terms = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.description)
```

Y estos son los formularios de donde se va a recoger la información:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Invoice, Item

class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('vendor','client', 'number', 'date', 'due_date')
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            'due_date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }


class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('description', 'quantity', 'rate', 'amount',
            'subtotal', 'tax', 'notes', 'terms')
```

Mi duda es como hago referencia en el template a alguno de los campos de `ItemForm` para que capture los datos?

Porque al menos con `InvoiceForm` no tengo problemas, me los muestra. Por ejemplo si hago esto no tengo incovenientes:

```
<!-- Client -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
    <label for="{{ form.client.id_for_label }}">Client</label>
    {{ form.client }}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4 offset-s4">
    <label for="{{ form.due_date.id_for_label }}">Due Date</label>
    {{ form.due_date }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero al intentar hacer referencia a algún campo de `ItemForm` no se como deberia hacerse. Por ejemplo si quiero en el template mostrar el campo `description` de `ItemForm` como deberia hacer? Porque si intento algo asi, no me muestra nada:

```
<div class="input-field col s5">
{{ form.description }}
</div>
```

Esta es mi vista, aunque tampoco sé como conectar ambos formularios, por ahora solo me interesa al menos que se muestren correctamente en el template:

```
def invoice_generator(request):
    form = InvoiceForm
    return render(request, 'invoiceapp/invoice_generator.html', {'form': form})
```

Quizás estoy mal enfocado o me estoy complicando, pero en realidad no se como proceder.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás pasando los formularios en tu `views.py`?

Comment: Ya incluí el views.py, pero para no hacer multiples preguntas, por ahora me interesa resolver lo de incluir los campos de ItemForm en el template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En general, cuando trabajas con ese tipo de relaciones (`Autor/Libro`, `Factura/Item`, etc.) lo que deberías usar son [`Formsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/) que te ayudan a trabajar con múltiples formularios en la misma vista.

En este caso puedes usar un [`InlineFormset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import InvoiceForm, ItemForm


def invoice_generator(request):
    ItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        Invoice,
        Item,
        form=ItemForm,
        fields=('description', 'quantity', 'rate', 'amount', 'subtotal', 'tax'),
        extra=4
    )
    form = InvoiceForm()
    formset = ItemFormSet()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InvoiceForm(request.POST)
        formset = ItemFormSet(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            form.save()
            formset.save()
            url = reverse('alguna_url')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    return render(request, 'invoiceapp/invoice_generator.html', {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset
    })
```

Y en tu template `invoice_generator.html`:

```
...
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <!-- La factura -->
    {{ form.vendor.label_tag }}
    {{ form.vendor }}
    ...

    <!-- Los items -->
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.id }}
        {{ form.description }}
        {{ form.quantity }}
        ...
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>
...
```

Algunas consideraciones:

- El parámetro `form` del `inlineformset_factory` es opcional, yo lo estoy usando debido a que ya habías definido tu formulario.
- El parámetro `extra` del `inlineformset_factory` sirve para indicar la cantidad de `items` que tendrás inicialmente, es decir, tu factura aparecerá con 4 formularios para `Item`.
- Cuando usas `FormSets` y renderizas manualmente los formularios tienes que definir el [`management_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template) (`{{ formset.management_form }}`)
- Cuando usas `FormSets` y renderizas manualmente los formularios tienes que indicar el `id` para que funcione correctamente (`{{ form.id }}`)

Comment: Al final decidi tomar otra ruta que me sugirieron en el stackoverflow en inglés [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459323/using-field-of-a-related-model-in-a-django-template] y me parecio más sencilla de implementar de acuerdo a mi nivel por el momento. Cuando pruebe tu solución la aceptare.

Comment: @JavierCárdenas eso solo sirve para un item por factura

Comment: Cesar tu solución funciona si agrego con jquery más items a la factura o tengo que hacer algo adicional?

Comment: @JavierCárdenas si es posible, tendrías que actualizar algunas cosas en el `management_form`, crea una pregunta para ayudarte ya que esta pregunta no está relacionada

Comment: Ok, estoy probando este, también me lo ha recomendado uno de los responsables de Wagtail, apenas lo pruebe comento el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hice utilizando una vista basada en clase:

```
Createview
```

Y formularios diferentes para cada modelo, y sobreescribiendo el método `get_context_data` de la clase:

```
class EmpleadosCreate(CreateView):
    model = Empleado
    form_class = EmpleadoForm
    second_form_class = DireccionForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('empleados:empleados_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmpleadosCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['active_client'] = True
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(self.request.GET)
        context['active_client'] = True
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        form2 = self.second_form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            usuario = form.save(commit=False)
            usuario.direccion = form2.save()
            usuario.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
              self.get_context_data(form=form, form2=form2))
```

Comment: Con tu código, ¿es posible agregar múltiples direcciones por cada empleado o solo una dirección?