# ¿Cómo hacer formularios InlineForm estilo django admin?

Tags: python, django, formularios

Para un proyecto que estoy desarrollando necesito construir un formulario de inscripción que va a guardar dos objetos al mismo tiempo, uno es campo foráneo de otro.

Esto con Django Admin se resuelve usando `StackedInlineForm`, pero en formularios comunes no sé hacerlo. Necesito un formulario para poder pasar ese formulario a un modelo de página Wagtail.

He leído que se construye con formsets pero no sé usarlo, y deseo usar `fieldsets` para agrupar correctamente los campos del formulario.

Este es el código del `admin.py`:

```
class AffiliationInline(admin.StackedInline):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {
            'fields': ['person', 'affiliation', 'is_active'],
        }),
        (None, {
            'fields': ['date_in', ],
        }),
    ]
    model = Affiliation
    # suit_classes = 'suit-tab suit-tab-affiliation'


class AffiliatesAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (_('Affiliate'), {
            'classes': ('suit-tab suit-tab-general',),
            'fields': ['name', 'logo', 'dni', 'attorney_name', 'position'],
        }),
        (_('Location'), {
            'classes': ('suit-tab suit-tab-general',),
            'fields': ['address', 'country', 'city', 'tel', 'fax', 'e_mail', 'web'],
        }),
        (_('Economic information'), {
            'classes': ('suit-tab suit-tab-general',),
            'fields': ['staff', 'interest', 'cause', 'economic_sector', 'economic_activity', 'other_interest'],
        })
    ]

    inlines = [AffiliationInline, ]
```

Este es el código que tengo en `forms.py`:

```
class AffiliationInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Affiliation
        fields =['person', 'affiliation']


class AffiliatesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Affiliates
        fieldsets = '__all__'
```

¿Cómo puedo emular el comportamiendo del admin con formularios?

El resultado me debe dar otro formulario o un objeto único que pueda interactuar con una página de Wagtail.

**Actualización:**

He conseguido hacer el formulario junto con un formulario embebido, el `formset` e imprimirlos en pantalla sin error alguno al imprimir:

```
def serve(self, request):
    from .forms import AffiliatesForm, AffiliationInlineForm

    AffiliationFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
            Affiliates,
            Affiliation,
            form=AffiliationInlineForm,
            fields=['person', 'affiliation', ],
            extra=1
    )
    form = AffiliatesForm()
    formset = AffiliationFormSet()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AffiliatesForm(request.POST)
        formset = AffiliationFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            form = form.save()
            formset = formset.save()

            return render(request, 'form_page_landing.html', {
                'page': self,
                'formset': formset,
                'form': form,
            })
    else:
        form = AffiliatesForm()
        formset = AffiliationFormSet()

    return render(request, 'form_page.html', {
        'page': self,
        'formset': formset,
        'form': form,
    })
```

Este es la plantilla para imprimir la página:

```
 <form action="." method="POST" data-abide novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {# form.as_p #}
        {{ formset.management_form }}

        <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="form-tabs">
            <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#affiliation" aria-selected="true">{% trans 'Affiliation' %}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#affiliate">{% trans 'Affiliate' %}</a></li>
            <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#location">{% trans 'Location' %}</a></li>
            <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#economic">{% trans 'Economic information' %}</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="form-tabs">
            <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="affiliation">
                <fieldset class="fieldset">
                    <legend>{% trans 'Affiliation' %}</legend>
                    {% for form in formset %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                                        <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.person.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                            {% if form.person.required %}
                                                <span class="required">{{ form.person.label }}</span>
                                            {% else %}
                                                {{ form.person.label }}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                                        {{ form.person }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                                        <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.affiliation.name }}"
                                               class="text-right middle">
                                            {% if form.affiliation.required %}
                                                <span class="required">{{ form.affiliation.label }}</span>
                                            {% else %}
                                                {{ form.affiliation.label }}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                                        {{ form.affiliation }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-panel" id="affiliate">
                <fieldset class="fieldset">
                    <legend>{% trans 'Affiliate' %}</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.name.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.name.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.name.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.name.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.name }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.logo.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.logo.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.logo.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.logo.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.logo }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.dni.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.dni.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.dni.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.dni.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.dni }}
                            {% if form.dni.help_text %}
                                <label for="id_{{ form.dni.name }}" class="help-text"
                                       id="id_{{ form.dni.name }}_helptext">{{ form.dni.help_text }}</label>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.attorney.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.attorney.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.attorney.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.attorney.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.attorney_name }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.position.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.position.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.position.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.position.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.position }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-panel" id="location">
                <fieldset class="fieldset">
                    <legend>{% trans 'Location' %}</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.address.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.address.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.address.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.address.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.address }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.country.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.country.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.country.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.country.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.country }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.city.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.city.required %}
                                    <span class="required">
                                    {{ form.city.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.city.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.city }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.tel.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.tel.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.tel.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.tel.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.tel }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.fax.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.fax.required %}
                                    <span class="required">
                                    {{ form.fax.label }}/span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.fax.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.fax }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.e_mail.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.e_mail.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.e_mail.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.e_mail.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.e_mail }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.web.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.web.required %}
                                    <span class="required">
                                    {{ form.web.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.web.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.web }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-panel" id="economic">
                <fieldset class="fieldset">
                    <legend>{% trans 'Economic information' %}</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.staff.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.staff.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.staff.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.staff.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.staff }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.interest.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.interest.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.interest.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.interest.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.interest }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.cause.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.cause.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.cause.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.cause.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.cause }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.economic_sector.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.economic_sector.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.economic_sector.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.economic_sector.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.economic_sector }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            {% if form.economic_activity.required %}
                                <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.economic_activity.name }}"
                                       class="text-right middle">
                                <span class="required">
                                    {{ form.economic_activity.label }}</span>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ form.economic_activity.label }}
                            {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.economic_activity }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <label for="middle-label id_{{ form.other_interest.name }}" class="text-right middle">
                                {% if form.other_interest.required %}
                                    <span class="required">{{ form.other_interest.label }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ form.other_interest.label }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            {{ form.other_interest }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="float-center hollow button secondary" type="reset" name="{% trans 'Reset' %}"
               style="margin-top: 1rem">
        <input class="float-center hollow button secondary" type="submit" name="{% trans 'Send' %}"
               style="margin-top: 1rem">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

El problema es que a pesar de que he colocado ese `instance=form.instance` para evitar un error que me decía que no se podía guardar el formulario por posible perdida de datos al no haberse guardado el objeto `affiliates`, no he conseguido que se guarden los dos modelos encadenados, por lo cuál nunca se guarda alguno de los dos.

Una primera instancia, sin haber puesto esos `instance`, pude guardar el formulario principal, afiliado, sin poder crear una afiliación al tiempo que estuviera encadenada al Afiliado y a la Membresía, osea, sólo se creaba el afiliado y nada más.

Estoy empezando a preguntarme si el problema es con django-smart-selects, que es el que uso para imprimis encadenados los dos selects del formset.

Como puedo resolver este problema?

**Actualización:**
He agregado el campo que faltaba en el formset: `{{ form.id }}`, y obtuve el siguiente problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se guardaba el formulario padre pero no guardaba los formularios hijos y me daba ese error. 
Sin embargo cambie el orden de guardado, guardando primero el formulario incluido y luego el formulario padre:

```
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
               formset = formset.save()
                form = form.save()
```

Guardamos primero el formulario hijo, y ahí si el formulario padre, lógicamente.

Y con esto me aparece un error nuevo, pero tiene que ver con un paquete adicional que estoy usando: django-smart-selects.

Comment: Hola, tal vez [Mostrar campos de modelos relacionados en el template de django](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1783/mostrar-campos-de-modelos-relacionados-en-el-template-de-django) y [Utilizar inline - formsets con contenido creado dinámicamente](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1918/utilizar-inline-formsets-con-contenido-creado-din%C3%A1micamente/1923#1923) te ayuden

Comment: Amigo, según el reglamento no puedes dar comentarios que sean respuestas, para eso son las respuestas :D.

Comment: Los pongo porque en esas preguntas hay temas muy parecidos al que tu quieres realizar, si es asi no vale la pena repetir una respuesta a algo que ya ha sido respondido. Si esas respuestas no te ayudan entonces edita ty pregunta indicando que es lo que te falta

Comment: Al final lo pude hacer, y quisiera publicar acá a modo de respuesta lo que hice, pero no puedo.
Me sirvió mucho esas preguntas, muchas gracias.

Comment: He actualizado esta pregunta también.

Comment: Este formulario, ¿es de creación, de edición, o de ambas?

Comment: Única y exclusivamente de Creación, es para que el usuario se inscriba, inscriba su empresa, y nada más, editar y eso lo hacen los administradores desde el Administrador de Django.

Comment: Si es de edición, no deberìas de tener que usar el parámetro `instance` ya que eso solo se usa cuando quieres editar.

Comment: Perfecto, entonces lo voy a quitar, eso explica por qué la primera vez no me daba ese error raro, y la segunda vez ya me daba el error, resulta que creaba el objeto Afiliado, pero como no se guardaba el objeto Afiliación, entonces me redireccionaba a la misma página, por lo cuál lo que hacía era mandar el mismo objeto a editar.

Pero este no me resuelve el por qué no guarda el objeto Afiliado.

Comment: Queria decir que si es **creación** no necesitas el parámetro `instance`, por favor actualiza tu pregunta con el código actualizado

Comment: Ya actualicé la pregunta amigo.

Comment: Bien, pero ahora te ha faltado mostrar como estás renderizando el formulario en tu template ya que no veo en tu código nada raro

Comment: Listo, actualizado, con respecto a la otra pregunta, muchas gracias hombre, esa fue la respuesta, aunque me gustaría que me ayudaras a refinar la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Creo que deberías intentar al revés, primero guarda el form y luego el formset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pues ya me di el tiempo de revisarlo bien y me parece que el problema es que no estás mostrando el `form.id` en el template, esto lo debes usar para que funcione correctamente al momento de hacer el `POST` del formulario.

Por ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.id }}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ form.name }}</li>
            <li>{{ form.age }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

En tu caso sería:

```
<form action="." method="POST" data-abide novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}

    ...

    <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="form-tabs">
        <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="affiliation">
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <legend>{% trans 'Affiliation' %}</legend>
                {% for form in formset %}
                    {{ form.id }}
                    <div class="row">            
                        ...
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Esto está documentado en la sección [Using the formset in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template) y también estaba mencionado en las consideraciones finales de mi respuesta a la pregunta [Mostrar campos de modelos relacionados en el template de django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1794/100).

Comment: Creo que he encontrado el problema, no estoy seguro, por lo cuál voy a actualizar la pregunta.